# xampp Error al leer de la base de datos

Tags: xampp, moodle

estaba realizando la instalación de Moodle en forma local, descargue y descomprimí en Moodle en la carpeta de htdocs de xampp, además en xampp creé una base de datos, pero al momento de descargar Moodle y conectarse con la base de datos sale un error que dice Error al leer de la base de datos. Como podría proseguir con la instalación de Moodle de forma local.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: estoy 100% seguro que es un error de configuracion de tu entorno o de tu codigo php, o del servidor de base de datos.

Comment: Hola Jordi, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código y los mensajes de error (si es que los recibes) en formato texto, y que nos expliques en que falla, mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!